# jobberBase php installation is not working

Tags: php, softaculous

I installed jobberBase using automatic installation (softaculous) on arvixe. As this was all automatic installation chances of any errors are rare. Still I did double checked that database got created fine; also the configuration looked fined.

I saw this errors on many other threads too but couldnt find a solution anywhere ; so looks like its a common installation problem. Most probably  the php are not able to connect to DB ! Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli() expects parameter 5 to be long, string given in /home/muskete3/public_html/jobber/_includes/class.Db.php on line 20

Warning: mysqli::query() [mysqli.query]: Couldn't fetch Db in /home/muskete3/public_html/jobber/_includes/class.Db.php on line 72

Warning: mysqli_error() [function.mysqli-error]: Couldn't fetch Db in /home/muskete3/public_html/jobber/_includes/class.Db.php on line 73

Warning: mysqli::query() [mysqli.query]: Couldn't fetch Db in /home/muskete3/public_html/jobber/_includes/class.Db.php on line 31

Warning: mysqli_error() [function.mysqli-error]: Couldn't fetch Db in /home/muskete3/public_html/jobber/_includes/class.Db.php on line 32

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/muskete3/public_html/jobber/_includes/class.JobberSettings.php on line 23
```

---

My configuration file is :

```
<?php
/**
 * Define environments
 *
 */

// local (http://localhost/jobberbase/public)
$__instances['local'] = array(
    // should be a unique part of the url (or the entire url if you wish)
    'prefix' => 'www.jobs41.net',
    // mysql credentials
    'db_host' => 'localhost',
    'db_port' => 3306,
    'db_user' => '***',
    'db_password' => '***',
    'db_name' => '***',
    'db_prefix' => '',
    // your site's full url
    'app_url' => 'http://www.jobs41.net/jobber/',
    // error reporting
    'ini_error_reporting' => E_ALL,
    'ini_display_errors' => 'On',
    // environment setting 1 (use 'local' for localhost/testing OR 'online' for live, production environment)
    'location' => 'local',
    // environment setting 2 (use 'dev' together with 'local' in the previous setting OR 'prod' with 'online')
    'environment' => 'dev',
    //'apache_mod_rewrite', 'iis_url_rewrite' -microsoft URL Rewrite module, 'iis_isapi_rewrite'
    'rewrite_mode' => 'apache_mod_rewrite'
);

// live (http://www.yourjobberbasedomain.com)
$__instances['live'] = array(
    'prefix' => 'www.jobs41.net',
    'db_host' => 'localhost',
    'db_port' => 3306,
    'db_user' => 'muskete3_jobb563',
    'db_password' => '6Sn82hxv7P',
    'db_name' => 'muskete3_jobb563',
    'db_prefix' => '',
    'app_url' => 'http://www.jobs41.net/jobber/',
    'ini_error_reporting' => E_ALL,
    'ini_display_errors' => 'Off',
    'location' => 'online',
    'environment' => 'prod',
    'rewrite_mode' => 'apache_mod_rewrite'
);
```

Comment: Please consult your host vendor / softaculous support for your problem.

Comment: Way to post your db username and password..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously I had installed it not as root directory; hence it was installed inside public_html/job.. Now when i installed it again in root directory it worked fine.